# ! Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `pdfmark',

Tags: pdftex, hyperref

This is my first ever using LaTeX, I received a template header from my university to use. Still had done no changes to it whatsoever and I get this error:

```
! Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `pdfmark',
```

The part of the code that is failing is the following:

```
\ifpdf %pdflatex
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \pdfcompresslevel=1
    \pdfimageresolution=300
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png}
    \graphicspath{{./pictures/}}
    \usepackage[hyperindex,pdfmark,pdftex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=tumblue,citecolor=citegreen,urlcolor=mailviolet,filecolor=linkred]  {hyperref}
\else %latex && dvips
    \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}%.bmp,.tif,.tiff,.tga}
    \graphicspath{{./pictures/}}
    \usepackage[hyperindex,pdfmark,dvips,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=tumblue,citecolor=citegreen,urlcolor=mailviolet,filecolor=linkred]{hyperref}
\fi
```

Comment: I've already seen some of the other questions about this and tried 2 fixes suggested both did not work as it resulted in a clash of some sort.

Comment: you should remove the pdfmark option from hyperref (you should also remove dvips and pdftex option from hyperref and graphicx

Comment: you can replace _all_ of the code shown by `\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage[hyperindex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=tumblue,citecolor=citegreen,urlcolor=mailviolet,filecolor=linkred]{hyperref}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for the tip, I did something else though no idea if what I did was right or wrong but it fixed it? At least it's running.

if the (if pdf) I replaced `pdfmark` with `driverfallback=pdfmark`  and in the (else) replaced `pdfmark` with `driverfallback=dvipdfm`  but kept `dvips` . 

Is what I did wrong, should I implement your version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shown is trying to specify different driver options for `graphicx` and `hyperref` and passing the incorrect options in some cases. However the tests are unnecessary as both packages will automatically detect whether they are being used with pdflatex or latex and choose the correct driver.

So the code can be simplified to

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hyperindex,colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=tumblue,citecolor=citegreen,urlcolor=mailviolet,
     filecolor=linkred]{hyperref}
```